# Hibernate Envers : Get REVEND_TSTMP from revision entity

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'd like to get `REVEND_TSTMP` value from a revision entity.

Currently I'm using :

```
AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery()
    .forRevisionsOfEntity(TestEntity.class, false, true)
    .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(entity.getUUID()));
```

Which gives me a list of arrays :

```
[ {TestEntity@XXXXX,DefaultRevisionEntity(id = 10, revisionDate = 05-sept.-2014 15:16:44),MOD} ]
```

How could I include `revisionEndDate` to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible currently I'm afraid - but please add a feature request!

Comment: Nevermind. I found the way to retrieve the value via HQL but it's actually not optimal for the current context. Thanks for your answer anyway. Where should I add a feature request?

Comment: In the [Hibernate JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa), Envers component

Comment: Hi Smoky, How do you to retrieve the value via HQL?? kindly provide a sample code.. am having the same problem...